# Transaction Support for Springs onMessage handler

Tags: java, spring, jms, jta, spring-jms

So I have some boilerplate code that consumes messages from a topic:

```
    public void onMessage(Message message )
{
    try
    {
        // try my conversion
    }
    catch(MyConversionException e)
    {
        //catch conversion error but still consume off topic
    }

    //Any other error i.e. runtime errors will not cause the message to be consumed from topic. So it can be retried

}
```

I wish to be able to try to convert the message into another object. If this causes an error I will catch it with my own exception handling and write it to an error queue.

My question is, how do I set up Springs messageListenerContainer bean to be Transactional and only consume if this has taken place successfully???

**[EDIT]**   Here is the bean so far:

```
    <!-- MESSAGE LISTENER CONTAINER -->
<bean id="ListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="messageListener" ref="MessageListener" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="Tcf" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="JmsDestinationResolver" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${jms-timeout}" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${jms-topic}" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="1" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="${jms-durable-flag}"/>
    <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="${jms-durable-name}" />
    <property name="clientId" value="${jms-client-id}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is not recommended to do so, but you can call TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly().

Also you may want to consider to be consistent with the transaction model, and if you want to rollback, then do it through an exception... In that case... You need to throw a RuntimeException so that Spring rollbacks the message, if you catch the exception and only logs it, Spring has no clue that something went wrong...

Comment: I wish to catch my own exception but not consume anything that throws any other exception.

Comment: Try TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()